# my VS2008 cannot connect to Sql Server 2008, why?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

MS Visual 2008 studio says "only servers up to 2005 are supported" when connecting SQL Server 2008?

how to get around this?

Comment: I know SP1 will fix it, but other solutions?

Comment: There's no reason to not upgrade to SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost certain that you need VS2008 SP1.  The two were released in parallel, and there was a lot of coordination between them to get things working.  I sincerely doubt that there are any ways to get SQL 2008 to work properly without VS2008 SP installed.